# detect the opening of an app like Waze and retrieve the entered route

Tags: ios, mobile, waze

Is it possible to create an application on iOS or Android that would detect the opening of an app like Waze and retrieve the entered route?

The application could then open a notification afterwards, for example?

If it is indeed feasible, I am not quite sure what to look for

Comment: Definitely not on iOS. Probably not on Android.

Comment: I guess...thanks for your review